# SourceTree app, how do I know what is my current branch?

Tags: git, gitflow

I have branched from my `develop` branch `bugfix/issue2` to work on a bugfix. Now that it's done I want to merge this branch `bugfix/issue2` back onto `develop` but it's asking me if I want to merge into my current branch. And I don't know if my current branch is `develop`?

See attached screendumps:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For one, the current branch is always the leftmost of the "Graph" lines and the current node you're on is highlighted, secondly the current branch is bold and has a little checkmark icon in the "Branches" sidebar.

You are currently on `bugfix/issue2`.

Comment: I don't understand then. It's asking if I want to merge `bugfix/issue2` onto my current branch (which is also `bugfix/issue2`)? I want to choose what branch to merge `bugfix/issue2` onto (I want to merge it onto `develop`)

Comment: Yeah, you're trying to merge a branch into itself (which just won't do anything). The git way to do it, and the way SourceTree wants you to do it as well, is to switch to the target branch (double click on it in the sidebar), then hit Merge and select what you want to merge into the current branch. You may want to check out the help file for Git Flow, which makes this somewhat easier and more structured.

Comment: It is weird that SourceTree only has Git Flow options for hotfixes (bugfixes occurring in release/master branch) but not regular bugfixes (bugfixes occurring in develop branch)

Comment: Don't take the terminology too literally, they're just names for *typical usage*, and they couldn't cram it all into one word to cover *every* possible scenario. Git Flow New Feature can perfectly well be used for bug fixes on the develop branch. A New Feature just branches off the develop branch and merges back into it. A New Release is the process for updating master from develop. A Hotfix is the procedure for updating master *and* develop at the same time. It means nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: @deceze Are the color of the lines assigned randomly or do they represent anything (gray for master, pink for branch)?

Comment: @Isuru I don't know. I'd guess more or less random, no real meaning can be ascribed to them.